# How to locate a row in a web table with specific input cell values

Tags: javascript, jquery

If I have to send an array of my input fields  such as `var arr=["Tiger",69,"Edinburgh"]`, the jQuery must be able to locate a row containing the `name:Tiger` of `Age:69` and `place:Edinburgh`. The array of inputs can be of any size and shall accordingly identify the column and row in the web table.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance!

```html
<table id="example" class="display" width="100%">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Position</th>
      <th>Office</th>
      <th>Age</th>
      <th>Start date</th>
      <th>Salary</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Tiger</td>
      <td>System Architect</td>
      <td>Edinburgh</td>
      <td>61</td>
      <td>2011/04/25</td>
      <td>$320,800</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Garrett Winters</td>
      <td>Accountant</td>
      <td>Tokyo</td>
      <td>63</td>
      <td>2011/07/25</td>
      <td>$170,750</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Ashton Cox</td>
      <td>Junior Technical Author</td>
      <td>San Francisco</td>
      <td>66</td>
      <td>2009/01/12</td>
      <td>$86,000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Cedric Kelly</td>
      <td>Senior Javascript Developer</td>
      <td>Edinburgh</td>
      <td>22</td>
      <td>2012/03/29</td>
      <td>$433,060</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Airi Satou</td>
      <td>Accountant</td>
      <td>Tokyo</td>
      <td>33</td>
      <td>2008/11/28</td>
      <td>$162,700</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Brielle Williamson</td>
      <td>Integration Specialist</td>
      <td>New York</td>
      <td>61</td>
      <td>2012/12/02</td>
      <td>$372,000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Tiger</td>
      <td>System Architect</td>
      <td>Edinburgh</td>
      <td>69</td>
      <td>2011/04/25</td>
      <td>$320,800</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Herrod Chandler</td>
      <td>Sales Assistant</td>
      <td>San Francisco</td>
      <td>59</td>
      <td>2012/08/06</td>
      <td>$137,500</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Rhona Davidson</td>
      <td>Integration Specialist</td>
      <td>Tokyo</td>
      <td>55</td>
      <td>2010/10/14</td>
      <td>$327,900</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Colleen Hurst</td>
      <td>Javascript Developer</td>
      <td>San Francisco</td>
      <td>39</td>
      <td>2009/09/15</td>
      <td>$205,500</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Sonya Frost</td>
      <td>Software Engineer</td>
      <td>Edinburgh</td>
      <td>23</td>
      <td>2008/12/13</td>
      <td>$103,600</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Jena Gaines</td>
      <td>Office Manager</td>
      <td>London</td>
      <td>30</td>
      <td>2008/12/19</td>
      <td>$90,560</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: what have you done so far ? were is the jQuery part ? can you show some code ?

Comment: Use `$("#example tr").filter(...)` and then write a function that tests the cells to see if they match your criteria.

Comment: I'm working on it for like more than a week. I'm not finding any solution that can be used to locate a row . The solution must be a generalized one for all the columns in the web table.

Answer (score 0):

**ANSWER UPDATE**

> What can be the solution if I send a dictionary with column names and the search input..for example :
>
> var dict={"Name":"Tiger","Age":69};

From your comment I propose you the following solution:

- from the dict element compute the corresponding table col indexes
- for each table row: test if every element satisfies all the conditions

```js
//
// let's assume we are looking for:
//
var dict={"Name":"Tiger","Age":69};

//
// Let's create the correspondence betwen column name and column index
//
var colIdx = {};

$('#example thead tr th').filter(function(idx, ele) {
   var keyName = ele.textContent;
    var keyValue = Object.keys(dict).indexOf(keyName);
    if (keyValue != -1) {
        colIdx[keyName] = idx;
    }
});

//
// For each table row in the body section
//
var colIndexes = Object.keys(colIdx);
$('#example tbody tr').filter(function(idx, ele) {
    var fVal = colIndexes.filter(function(colName, idx) {
        var colValue = dict[colName];
        var colIndex = colIdx[colName];
        return ($(ele).find('td').eq(colIndex).text() == colValue)
    });
    // if all conditions are satisfied...
    return fVal.length == colIndexes.length;
}).css('background-color', 'red')
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<table id="example" class="display" width="100%">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Position</th>
        <th>Office</th>
        <th>Age</th>
        <th>Start date</th>
        <th>Salary</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>Tiger</td>
        <td>System Architect</td>
        <td>Edinburgh</td>
        <td>61</td>
        <td>2011/04/25</td>
        <td>$320,800</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Garrett Winters</td>
        <td>Accountant</td>
        <td>Tokyo</td>
        <td>63</td>
        <td>2011/07/25</td>
        <td>$170,750</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Ashton Cox</td>
        <td>Junior Technical Author</td>
        <td>San Francisco</td>
        <td>66</td>
        <td>2009/01/12</td>
        <td>$86,000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Cedric Kelly</td>
        <td>Senior Javascript Developer</td>
        <td>Edinburgh</td>
        <td>22</td>
        <td>2012/03/29</td>
        <td>$433,060</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Airi Satou</td>
        <td>Accountant</td>
        <td>Tokyo</td>
        <td>33</td>
        <td>2008/11/28</td>
        <td>$162,700</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Brielle Williamson</td>
        <td>Integration Specialist</td>
        <td>New York</td>
        <td>61</td>
        <td>2012/12/02</td>
        <td>$372,000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Tiger</td>
        <td>System Architect</td>
        <td>Edinburgh</td>
        <td>69</td>
        <td>2011/04/25</td>
        <td>$320,800</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Herrod Chandler</td>
        <td>Sales Assistant</td>
        <td>San Francisco</td>
        <td>59</td>
        <td>2012/08/06</td>
        <td>$137,500</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Rhona Davidson</td>
        <td>Integration Specialist</td>
        <td>Tokyo</td>
        <td>55</td>
        <td>2010/10/14</td>
        <td>$327,900</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Colleen Hurst</td>
        <td>Javascript Developer</td>
        <td>San Francisco</td>
        <td>39</td>
        <td>2009/09/15</td>
        <td>$205,500</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Sonya Frost</td>
        <td>Software Engineer</td>
        <td>Edinburgh</td>
        <td>23</td>
        <td>2008/12/13</td>
        <td>$103,600</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Jena Gaines</td>
        <td>Office Manager</td>
        <td>London</td>
        <td>30</td>
        <td>2008/12/19</td>
        <td>$90,560</td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: It is not necessary that I choose only name, age and office all the time. I may change the column names. Accordingly it should filter out the rows.

Comment: What can be the solution if I send a dictionary with column names and the search input..for example : var dict={"Name":"Tiger","Age":69};

Comment: I have another doubt. Can I send the column index values like var dict ={0:"Tiger",3:69}.

Comment: I have wriiten the following code so that the code can identify the row from a table using indexes or column names. But it is throwing some error. Can you let me know what is the mistake.